# Загрузка большого количества изображений с сервера: сохранять в кэш или не стоит?

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение, которое регулярно загружает большое количество изображений с сервера. Новые изображения подгружаются раз в 10 секунд, при этом одновременно нужны всегда разные изображения. Одно и то же сообщение загружается не чаще одного раза в 3 часа. Вопрос возник, есть ли смысл их кэшировать как либо или это того не стоит. изображения сами по себе малы (100х100 jpeg), но их общее количество близко к 2 000.

Comment: LRUcache используй

Comment: Если мы говорим о размерах кеша порядка гигабайтов, то кешировать стоит.

Comment: Согласен с @Cypher. Используйте LRU и создайте ограничение на время жизни кэша, смотря часто используются картинки или нет. Можно наверняка чистить кэш раз в 2-3 суток, что бы не засорять устройство пользователя.